# Correct data type for manipulating raw memory

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, c++17

I have a class that facilitates encoding/decoding raw memory.  I ultimately store a `void` pointer to point to the memory and the number of bytes being referenced.  I'm concerned about aliasing issues as well as the bit-shifting operations to get the encoding correct.  Essentially, for `WHAT_TYPE` should I use `char`, `unsigned char`, `int8_t`, `uint8_t`, `int_fast8_t`, `uint_fast8_t`, `int_least8_t`, or `uint_least8_t`?  Is there a definitive answer within the spec?

```
class sample_buffer {
    size_t index; // For illustrative purposes
    void *memory;
    size_t num_bytes;
public:
    sample_buffer(size_t n) :
        index(0),
        memory(malloc(n)),
        num_bytes(memory == nullptr ? 0 : n) {
    }
    ~sample_buffer() {
        if (memory != nullptr) free(memory);
    }
    void put(uint32_t const value) {
        WHAT_TYPE *bytes = static_cast<WHAT_TYPE *>(memory);
        bytes[index] = value >> 24;
        bytes[index + 1] = (value >> 16) & 0xFF;
        bytes[index + 2] = (value >> 8) & 0xFF;
        bytes[index + 3] = value & 0xFF;
        index += 4;
    }
    void read(uint32_t &value) {
        WHAT_TYPE const *bytes = static_cast<WHAT_TYPE const *>(memory);
        value = (static_cast<uint32_t>(bytes[index]) << 24) |
                (static_cast<uint32_t>(bytes[index + 1]) << 16) |
                (static_cast<uint32_t>(bytes[index + 2]) << 8) |
                (static_cast<uint32_t>(bytes[index + 3]);
        index += 4;
    }
};
```

Comment: Don't spam tags! C is not C++.

Comment: Since you say c++1z in the tags, the answer is obviously `std::byte`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In C++17: [`std::byte`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte). This type is specifically created precisely for this reason, to convey all the right semantic meaning. Moreover, it has all the operators you would need to use on raw data (like the `<<` in your example), but none of the operators that you wouldn't.

---

Before C++17: `unsigned char`. The standard defines object representation as a sequence of `unsigned char`, so it's just a good type to use. Furthermore, as [Mooing Duck rightly suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42937781/correct-data-type-for-manipulating-raw-memory/42937953?noredirect=1#comment72973141_42937953), using `unsigned char*` would prevent many bugs caused by mistakenly using your `char*` that refers to raw bytes as if it were a string and passing it into a function like `strlen`.

If you really cannot use `unsigned char`, then you should use `char`. Both `unsigned char` and `char` are the types you're allowed to alias through, so either are preferred to any of the other integer types.

Comment: Also: _Please_ prefer `unsigned char` for bytes. I have seen _far_ too many bugs caused by someone calling `strlen`, `strcpy`, or `sprintf` on a `char*`.  `unsigned char` forces the developer to stop and think about if they're using the right functions.

Comment: Is std::byte too allowed to alias?